# break statement does not stop executing while loop Immediately in java

Tags: java, while-loop, break

I am trying to run a program that asks the user to list some values. These values will then be stored in a list and once the user types 0 the loop should terminate and the program should find the smallest and largest values the user had inputted.

the code where I initialise the loop to store the values is below:

```
    public static void main(String[] Args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("This program finds the largest and smallest numbers");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("?");
            int value = in.nextInt();
            if(value == 0) {break;}
            list.add(value);
        }
        System.out.println("smallest:" + findSmallest(list));
        System.out.println("largest:" + findLargest(list));
    }
```

Instead of the break statement exiting the while loop immediately before adding the input 0 to the list, it triggers only after the entire while loop had finished. For example If i type 5,3 and 0 I should get:

smallest:3
largest:5

but instead i get:

smallest:0
largest:5

Why is this happenning and how can I solve it?

For reference here is the entire code:

```
package Programs;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindRange {
    /* sentinel value for exiting the program*/
    private static final int sentinel = 0;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] Args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("This program finds the largest and smallest numbers");
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("?");
            int value = in.nextInt();
            if(value == 0) {break;}
            list.add(value);
        }
        System.out.println("smallest:" + findSmallest(list));
        System.out.println("largest:" + findLargest(list));
    }
    
    /* 
     * Precondition: We must receive a list of type ArrayList containing
     * int values provided by the user
     * PostConditions: Provides the smallest value in the list 
     * */
    private static int findSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        int smallest = list.get(0);
        for (int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
            if (i<smallest) {
                smallest = i;
            }
        }
        return smallest;
                }
    
    /* 
     * Precondition: We must receive a list of type ArrayList containing
     * int values provided by the user
     * PostConditions: Provides the Largest value in the list 
     * 
     * Error with code: Some reason break statement on main doesn't stop the execution of the loop straight away
     * resulting in the sentinel 0 being stored in the list. 
     * */
    private static int findLargest(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        int Largest = list.get(0);
        for (int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
            if (i>Largest) {
                Largest = i;
            }
        }
        return Largest;
                }
    

}
```

Comment: The find methods are wrong. You're putting i in smallest when you should be putting list.get(i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` is working correctly. The issue is in the implementations of `findSmallest` and `findLargest`. For instance, you have:

```
private static int findSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int smallest = list.get(0);
    for (int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
        if (i<smallest) {
            smallest = i;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Here, `i` is the **index**, not the *value* at that index. Also, your loop's condition is wrong. It's already exclusive, since you are using `<`, meaning you should not be subtracting one from the size of the list.

You want something like:

```
private static int findSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int smallest = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) < smallest) {
            smallest = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Or you can use a for-each loop:

```
private static int findSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    int smallest = list.get(0);
    for (Integer value : list) {
        if (value < smallest) {
            smallest = value;
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Similar changes need to be made for `findLargest`.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't compare items of the list with the smallest variable and the largest variable. You just compare the index of the for loop with them, so you need to change them as follows:

```
private static int findSmallest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int smallest = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) < smallest) {
            smallest = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}


private static int findLargest(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int Largest = list.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) > Largest) {
            Largest = list.get(i);
        }
    }
    return Largest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to keep an array. All you need is just two `int` values.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("This program finds the largest and smallest numbers.");
    System.out.println("Type '0' to exit the program.");

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    boolean empty = true;

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("> ");
        int val = scan.nextInt();

        if (val == 0) {
            break;
        }

        min = Math.min(min, val);
        max = Math.max(max, val);
        empty = false;
    }

    if (empty) {
        System.out.println("No input");
    } else {
        System.out.println("smallest: " + min);
        System.out.println("largest: " + max);
    }
}
```